# Tomcat is generating logs in multiple places, one in the default path "/logs" and another in the custom directory that is specified externally

Tags: linux, tomcat, amazon-ec2

We are planning to rotate the log that is generated by Tomcat using Logrotate for volume maintenance. When I checked for the logs I was able to find two places in which these logs were been generated "../apache-tomcat-7.0.57/logs" and in the path that is specified in the "logging.properties". I did check in the Tomcat document, from which I was able to understand that Tomcat uses the default path which is "/logs" is no path is mentioned externally in "logging.properties". I was not able to find if I have missed any configuration.

logging.properties file:

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = <custome path>
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = <custome path>
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = <custome path>
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = <custome path>
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

# For example, set the org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase logger to log
# each component that extends LifecycleBase changing state:
#org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.level = FINE

# To see debug messages in TldLocationsCache, uncomment the following line:
#org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.level = FINE
```

**My question is why are the logs getting generated in multiple places and how to make it log in just in one directory for maintaining the same ?**

Reference link

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html

Answer (score 0):

By default - It'll log to `${catalina.base}/logs` which is what you should see in `${catalina.base}/conf/logging.properties`

Additionally standard output (aka `exception.printStackTrace()`) goes into (by default) `${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.out`

`${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.out` can be set to a different file by setting the environment variable `CATALINA_OUT` or `CATALINA_OUT_CMD`. So see what `CATALINA_OUT_CMD` does - It'll be easier to read the comments in `${catalina.home}/bin/catalina.sh`